# Truncate number of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a method to limit the number of rows in a pandas dataframe, or is this best done by indexing, for example:

```
LIMIT = 1000
df = df[:LIMIT]
```

The reason I ask this is I may have million-row dataframes and I'd like to make sure this call is as efficient as possible, because I will be calling it quite a bit.

Comment: `df.head(LIMIT)`

Comment: Are you trying to limit the number of displayed rows?

Comment: hold on, TS wants to limit number of row or limit the size of the dataframe?

Comment: @addicted limit the actual size of the dataframe itself.

Comment: `df = df.iloc[0:LIMIT, :]` is probably fastest, but I'm not actually sure how it frees the now-unreferenced rows (there might be a bit of a memory problem for you).

Comment: @David542 are you trying to read your dataframe in chucks or is it already in memory and you are trying to return a view of your current dataframe?

Comment: It's ambiguous what you mean with "limit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various options available, but you need to be specific what you need.

I personally use these settings:

```
##### widen output display to see more columns and rows in `pandas` ####
pd.set_option('display.height', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 100)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
```

(100's above are just an example).

##### Extracting a subset of a `pandas DataFrame`:

In general this is how to subset portions of a `DataFrame`:

```
df.loc[start_row:end_row, start_column:end_column]
```

##### Selecting the initial `n` rows from a `DataFrame`:

```
df[:1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to limit the number of rows displayed, then the next command will be useful:

```
limit = 1000
pd.options.display.max_rows = limit
```

Or you could try to the next one:

```
limit = 1000
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",limit)
```

Comment: This limits the display of the dataframe not the size of the actual dataframe